# Windows Recovery Boot Key(configured using ReAgentc.exe) is not activate before passing OOBE setup after using windows Recovery

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, partition-recovery

I have deployed image window 7 image with factory reset on separate partition. I am able to recover the solution to factory fresh install but the problem i see here is after recovering to full reset. After booting when OOBE is starting , In case this OOBE is disturbed like power down or any manual interruption. On Next boot window installation error pops up and also Function boot key which i set using ReAgentc.exe also not working.  I get Window Error Recovery

During this time Fn Key[F11 using ReAgentc.exxe) I have configured for Windows Recovery is not working.

**Implementation Detail:**

Installing OS:

1. create partition
2. par 1 = Recovery partition = Label(R),set iD=27
3. System Boot partition = Label(S)
4. Window partition = label(W)
5. Copy Image to Recovery partition == R:\Recovery\WindowsRE\Install.wim,WinRe.Wim and Boot.sdi
6. Apply Image to W:\ using Image X tool
7. setting boot path W:\windows
8. Setting Recovery option to Fn11 key
   W:\Windows\System32\ReAgentc.exe /SetReImage /Target W:\Windows /Path R:\Recovery\WindowsRE /BootKey 0x8500
   W:\Windows\System32\ReAgentc.exe /SetOsImage /Target W:\Windows /Path R:\Recovery\WindowsRE

**Factory Resetting Implementation:**

1. Assign back all label to respective partition
2. format Drive W:\ and apply Install.wim from R:\Recovery\WindowsRE using Imagex tool
   3.Deleting Boot Enviroment W:\Windows\System32\Bcdboot.exe W:\windows /l EN-US /s S:

   4. Setting Recovery 
      W:\Windows\System32\ReAgentc.exe /SetReImage /Target W:\Windows /Path R:\Recovery\WindowsRE /BootKey 0x8500
      W:\Windows\System32\ReAgentc.exe /SetOsImage /Target W:\Windows /Path R:\Recovery\WindowsRE
      5.Shutdown
      Steps to repro:
3. Install Factory Setting by pressing F11
4. During OOBE , Plug out the power.
   Issue. Recovery partion is not accessible using registered Function Key F11
   Any help will be great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below code to fix or activate Recovery Sequence before OOBE

```
bcdedit.exe /CREATE {ramdiskoptions} /d "Ramdisk Options"
bcdedit.exe /SET {ramdiskoptions} ramdisksdidevice partition=R:
bcdedit.exe /SET {ramdiskoptions} ramdisksdipath \Recovery\WindowsRE\boot.sdi
for /f "tokens=2 delims={}" %%g in ('bcdedit.exe /create /d "W7 Recovery" /application osloader') do (set guid={%%g})
bcdedit.exe /SET %guid% device ramdisk=[R:]\Recovery\windowsRE\Winre.wim,{ramdiskoptions}
bcdedit.exe /SET %guid% path \Windows\system32\winload.exe
bcdedit.exe /SET %guid% osdevice ramdisk=[R:]\Recovery\windowsRE\Winre.wim,{ramdiskoptions}
bcdedit.exe /SET %guid% systemroot \windows
bcdedit.exe /SET %guid% winpe yes
bcdedit.exe /SET %guid% detecthal yes
bcdedit.exe /SET %guid% nx OptIn
bcdedit.exe /SET {globalsettings} extendedinput 1
bcdedit.exe /SET {BOOTMGR} custom:0x54000001 %guid%
bcdedit.exe /SET {BOOTMGR} customactions 0x1000085000001 0x54000001
```